# Spring-Boot-Maven-Plugin - Command to Copy Resources into WAR Main Directory

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

**QUESTION**

In a `Spring Boot` `Java` application built with `Maven` using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with `WAR` `packaging` through `Eclipse IDE` with `M2` with the goal as `clean package`, I would like to know if there is a command which would allow me to copy the resource folders (`css`, `images`, etc) which currently end up in `mywar.war/WEB-INF/classes/static/` into the root directory `mywar.war`, so that I have `mywar.war/images/`, etc?

I see that with other plugins, there is something like a `targetPath`, but I can't find anything like that in the documentation for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

**EXAMPLE POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>My Application</description>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.78</tomcat.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>x</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/MyJar.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Because those running the server I am going to deploy it to generally don't want to change their settings if ever possible, and their existing settings have the http server set up to allow proxypass for the /images/, /css/, etc folders in the root directory instead of in /WEB-INF/classes/static/images/, etc. Business as usual. :)

Comment: But what web framework are you using?

Comment: And in which directory do you have these files?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli This is a ``Spring Boot`` application in ``Java`` using ``Thymeleaf`` and running as a ``WAR`` on an ``Apache Tomcat`` server behind an ``Apache HTTP Server``. I have all of my resources in the project under ``/src/main/resources/static``, and they include ``/src/main/resources/static/images``, ``/src/main/resources/static/css``, etc.

Comment: But then everything will work as expected. The url will be <host>:<port>/<warname>/css etc.

Comment: The static directory is automatically mapped by Spring Boot as a subdirectory of the war, or if it's a standalone Spring Boot App, as the root.

Comment: Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade as soon as possible to Spring Boot 2.X cause Spring Boot 1.X will be EOL at August...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah, I agree - but unfortunately this version was another requirement. I actually first built the app with Spring Boot 2.x, only to find out that it could not run because the ``Tomcat Apache Server`` was too old to support it, and I had to regress the application to this back-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up getting around this by moving all of my resources from the `/src/main/resources/static` directory into a `/src/main/webapp` directory. Then everything appeared right under the root of the resulting `WAR` file, and the `Apache HTTP Server` picked them up and allowed them through.

Thanks for your insight, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Everything will work as expected. Spring Boot will server your static content.

The urls will be

```
<host>:<port>/<warname>/css 
<host>:<port>/<warname>/images
```

etc.

Comment: Hello - This is true, however, this does not resolve that the ``Apache HTTP Server`` needs to allow access to the files at ``mywar.war/WEB-INF/classes/static/``, etc for this to work without a 404 denied error on the client-side. My issue is that I need the files to be located at ``mywar.war/images`` to fulfill requirements.

Comment: No why do you think so? Do you use mod _jk or mod_proxy